# Синтаксис записи значений C

Tags: c, winapi, syntax

Всем привет, наткнулся я на одну статейку в интернете по работе с памятью на C++, где обнаружил такую строчку кода:

`*(PDWORD)&MyFunc = VTable[1];`

Где VTable - массив типа DWORD. Зная Microsoft, у них есть готовые имена для типов данных WIN32, так например, DWORD - unsigned long int; PDWORD - указатель на DWORD.

И так в этой строчке кода я вижу что:
1)берётся адрес функции MyFunc
2)происходит преобразование типа в PDWORD
3)Запись значения из массива VTable

Вопрос такой, для чего знак астериск (*) в начале строки? Куда происходит запись значения из массива, в адрес или указатель?

Что это вообще за синтаксис где стоит знак астериск в начале, но при этом происходит преобразование в тип указатель на DWORD, зачем это указывать два раза?

Comment: Функции winapi не случайны - они содержат несколько первых инструкций (в том числе один или два nop) в таком виде, что в это место можно записать инструкции вызова другой функции и таким образом перехватить вызов. Я бы предположил, что запись делается непосредственно в исполняемый код функции. Но точно сказать не могу.

Comment: Я тут дополнительно про синтаксис с указателями почитал. Так вот, к примеру, у нас есть нулевой указатель p: int *p = 0; и есть ссылка на указатель: int *&pRef = p; Тогда в нашем случае получается что MyFunc - ссылка на указатель которой присваивается значение массива VTable типа DWORD и для этого как раз и происходит приведение типа указателя к  PDWORD. Но всё же хотелось бы узнать как именно стоит понимать последовательность действий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Это код на `C`
2. Это плохой, непереносимый код на `C`, потому что на `x64` это работать нормально не будет
3. Это пример наглого [TypePunning](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

**Как работает в общем случае**

Берем указатель куда-то -  `&Myfunc`

Теперь внаглую говорим, что это, оказывается, указатель на `DWORD` - `(PDWORD)&Myfunc`

Потом разыменовываем это, уже как указатель на `DWORD` - `*(PDWORD)&Myfunc`

Пишем туда свое значение типа `DWORD` - `*(PDWORD)&Myfunc = VTable[1];`

**Обратите внимание**

`&` возле переменной имеет в `C` только один смысл - *дай мне указатель на это*. Ссылок в С просто нет.

Comment: Ясненько, спасибо за разъяснения. Это было приведение типов в стиле языка C, в C++ же нужно использовать static_cast<> и другие, которые язык поддерживает.

Comment: Для данного случая, нужен был бы reinterpret_cast<>

Comment: Ясненько, такая операция наименее безопасна, но позволяет интерпретировать значение в другой тип данных. Например, число int в указатель типа int.

Answer (score 0):

Так ещё делают для установки константного значения поля структуры, так как обычное присваивание в этом случае вызовет ошибку компилляции:

```
struct {
    const int a;
} st;

/* error: */
st.a = 10;

/* no error: */
*(int*)&st.a = 10;
```

Comment: Ясно спасибо. Как я вижу, приводим тип указателя к указателю типа int, дальше разыменовываем указатель типа int на поле структуры и пишем туда значение 10.

Comment: Более точно будет выглядеть так: так как приоритет доступа к полю структуры наибольший, то сперва обращаемся непосредственно к полю. Далее берём адрес этого поля и явно кастуем в int*. Ну и в конце разыменовываем указатель и кладём туда значение 10.